# strtotime not converting correct year

Tags: php, strtotime

I am trying to convert a date using [pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) mixed with PHP using [Laravel 4](http://laravel.com). The issue I am having is when I attempt to save dates that are > 2013. If I choose Jan 23th 2014 it will save as Jan 23th 2013.

This is what's being sent via `$_POST` to the date variable.

```
23 January, 2014
```

This is my setup

```
$date = strtotime($scheduler['date']);
```

Converts to UNIX 1358993640 (which reads Jan 23 2013)

```
$dateFormat = date('l: F d, Y',$date);
```

Which becomes:

```
Wednesday: January 23, 2013
```

Is there another function I could use? Or do I need to convert the time another way before `strtotime`? It works as long as it's 2013. So I am thinking once it hits 2014 it will work then also.

Comment: how you want to display??

Comment: @JakeGould That's probably due to your time zone :)

Comment: My timezone is Central. How would that effect it?

Comment: oh I am sorry I thought that was directed towards me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very strange. But found a fix. Testing on my local setup running PHP 5.5, it seems that the comma is what is causing the issue.  So stripping out commas from the entered data produces the desired results with your test code:

```
// Set the test data.
$test_data = '23 January, 2014';

// Filter out commas from the '$test_data'
$test_data = preg_replace('/,/', '', $test_data);

// Get the Unix datetime from the test data.
$date = strtotime($test_data);

// Format the Unix datetime.
$dateFormat = date('l: F d, Y', $date);  

// Output for debugging.
echo 'date: ' . $date . '<br />';
echo 'dateFormat: ' . $dateFormat . '<br />';
```

The output I get is:

```
date: 1390453200
dateFormat: Thursday: January 23, 2014
```

Comment: Right, that's basically what my answer mentioned as well :)

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking it could have been because of the comma. Not sure why pickadate.js formats it like that or if there is a way to change that. But i tried that and that seemed to fix the issue. Thanks for the example!

Comment: exactly. I chose pickadate.js becaude it seemed easy to use. Has not been the case. It has been in absolute nightmare. Especially with the Javascript library using 0 to start the month and PHP using 1...not fun at all but i have gone to far with it to turn back lol. Thanks again @JakeGould if I remember correctly you have helped me in the past with another issue I had! So thanks a ton!

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the textual date was created according to a fixed format, you can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) instead:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d F, Y', $scheduler['date']);
echo $date->format('l: F d, Y');
```

Alternatively, just omit the comma:

```
echo date('l: F d, Y', strtotime('23 January 2014'));
```

Comment: I used JakeGould method but will look into yours. I have never used that function before thanks!